# Homotopy classes of maps $\mathbb{R}^3 \to SO(3)$ and $\mathbb{R}^3 \to SU(2)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am learning about the classical and quantum mechanical Heisenberg model, especially its continuum limit. To get an idea of the possible patterns, I wonder what are the homotopy classes of continuous maps $\mathbb{R}^3 \to SO(3)$ resp. $\mathbb{R}^3 \to SU(2)$, but could not find either in my literature or online.

I am not only interested in a statement like "the homotopy class is $\mathbb{Z}$" but also a characterization of the mappings.

For example, thinking of $\mathbb{R}^3 \to SU(2)$, I can sketch at least two (homotopically distinct) mappings, one being the constant map and one being a homeomorphic map $S^3 \to SU(2)$ inside the unit ball (with the boundary compactified to a point) and constant and the boundary and outside. Both share one interesting property, namely that the preimage of all points but one is discrete whereas one point's preimage is three dimensional. Do all maps from $\mathbb{R}^3 \to SU(2)$ have a similar property?

(How) do the homotopy classes of continuous maps $\mathbb{R}^3 \to SO(3)$ and $\mathbb{R}^3 \to SU(2)$ differ?

Comment: Euclidean space has the homotopy type of a point.

Comment: The homotopy type of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the homotopy classes of the maps $S^1\to\mathbb{R}^3$, that's something completely different than the homotopy classes of maps $\mathbb{R}^3 \to SU(2)$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, the homotopy classes of based maps $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is the fundamental group $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3)$, which is trivial because $\mathbb{R}^3$ is contractible.  The "homotopy type" of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $\{*\}$, that of a point.  You can't find this in any literature because it is literally trivial.

Comment: In other words, the homotopy classes of maps $\mathbb{R}^3 \to SO(3)$ is **exactly** the same thing as the classes of maps $\{*\} \to SO(3)$, which isn't interesting at all.

Comment: Ok, this goes completely against my intuition. Maybe you can help me. In my question I sketched a map that resembles a homeomorphism $S^3 \to SU(2)$ inside a unit ball and stays constant outside. That homeomorphism is not null-homotopic in $S^3$. Now apparently the same map is null-homotopic in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If I try to construct that homotopy, contracting $\mathbb{R}^3$ to a point, I don't get how the step from a constant map to a surjective map can be continuous. In the end it just tells me that the concept of homotopy is apparently not what I'm looking for...

Comment: Ok, I think I got how it would work (if we grow the radius of the unit ball like $tan(t)$ then after a finite t, the boundary is at infinity. We can continue to grow the ball until the map is constant). If I'm right, it's equivalent to either transform the map itself or the domain. Allowing homotopy equivalent transformations of the domain gives us the homotopy classes of the map. Now if we only allow homeomorphic transformations that must yield a different equivalence relation on the maps $\mathbb{R}^3\to SU(2)$. How is it called and what are its equivalence classes?

Comment: I don't quite see how this map that is constant outside a unit ball could be continuous.

Comment: It would be constant on the boundary too. Now you can identify the boundary and everything outside as a single point and that gives you the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and therefore $S^3$. And $S^3$ is homeomorphic to $SU(2)$.Therefore, picking any homeomorphism $S^3 \to SU(2)$ yields a continuous map $\mathbb{R}^3 \to SU(2)$.

Comment: Randall correctly states that  $\mathbb  R^3$ is homotopy equivalent to a single-point space $*$. Thus the set of homotopy classes of maps $\mathbb R^3 \to X$ is in $1$-$1$-correspondence with the set of homotopy classes of maps $* \to X$.